# Change column values based on matching values from another table SQL

Tags: sql, excel

So I have two tables, one with a **key** and one with **rawdata**

Key:

| ID | Zone |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | c |

Raw Data:

| ID | DesignatedZone |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 |  |
| 2 |  |
| 1 |  |
| 3 |  |

I want to fill  the empty column in rawdata if the value in the ID columns match.

Desired Output:

| ID | DesignatedZone |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 2 | B |
| 1 | A |
| 3 | C |

Raw Data has 1000+ rows. Would a JOIN be the best way to tackle it or UPDATE? Im also open to an Excel solution as well since I can edit the data before I import it.

This was my guess:

```
    UPDATE rawdata
    SET rawdata.DesignatedZone = key.Zone
    WHERE rawdata.ID = key.ID
```

Comment: MySQL != BigQuery.  Which is your actual database?

Comment: BigQuery. The data set is uploaded from a CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Use an update join:

```sql
UPDATE rawdata r
SET r.DesignatedZone = k.Zone
FROM `Key` k
WHERE k.ID = r.ID;
```